# Identify a copper fuzzy moth

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Photographed in 2003 in Panama. Not sure of size.

[image: Moth]

Comment: Its a relative of dirphia horcana and dirphia brevifurca

Answer (score 1):

Cerodirphia avenata, a moth of the Saturniidae family. An anonymous person identified it. The person did not give any evidence, and I know nothing about moths, but its seemingly-distinctive wing markings wing frontal edges, and antennae match this [example image](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cerodirphia_avenata&oldid=1025212058#/media/File:Cerodirphia_avenata.jpg) on wikipedia and those I can see on iNaturalist [also made in Panama](https://panama.inaturalist.org/taxa/531780-Cerodirphia-avenata).

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer you found elsewhere. Please note that you are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that support this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this post is indistinguishable from opinion and thus is not appropriate as an answer on this site. ——— You may also wish to take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Ask] and [Answer] effectively on this site.

Comment: thanks, I've added a (quite likely naive) justification